# hiding an input element on cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Ι have a form where it has an input element where a user can enter the url-this happens when he clicks the edit button at which point the input fields appears.

If the user starts typing the url and clicks the cancel button what ever he was typing becomes null and the input field is hidden again from view(a class is added to the element with display:none).

And here is where the problem, appears:
If the user types something and clicks the save button the data(url) is sent to the server with an ajax request.That means the next time the forms loads the user will see the submitted url. If, at that point chooses to edit the form,and press the cancel button the submitted url is hidden from view...something not desirable of course because we are talking here about the submitted data.

How I can distinguish the one from the other,-submitted data and non-submitted data-on cancel.

Here is some code, first related to clicking the cancel button and secondly with the function which adds the classes to the input element:

```
$('#canceladrs').click(function() {  
var urlcancel=$.trim($('input#wwwaddress').val());
save=2;
close_url(save,urlcancel);       
closeaddress(); 

});

here is the close_url() function

function close_url(savearg,urlarg,cancelarg)
{
console.log(urlarg);
if(savearg===1)// save button clicking here
    { if(urlarg==='')
            {
              $('input#wwwaddress').addClass('hideurl');
              $('label[for=url]').addClass('hideurl');
              $('input#wwwaddress').val(null);
            } 
       else if(urlarg!=='')
           {
              $('input#wwwaddress').removeClass('hideurl');
              $('label[for=url]').removeClass('hideurl');
              $('input#wwwaddress').val(urlarg);
           }
    }
else if(savearg===2)//cancel button clicking here
{if((urlarg!=='')||(urlarg===''))
        {
            $('input#wwwaddress').addClass('hideurl');
              $('label[for=url]').addClass('hideurl');

        }
}


}

}
```

As you see above I am trying to mark the clicking of the cancel button setting save=2.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Can you please clarify when and why you are hiding and or showing things? Also jQuery already has `hide` and `fadeOut` you don't have to create your own classes for this.

Comment: I am hiding the field when it is empty or when the user started typing something at which point he pressed the cancel button. I do not want the element hidden when:input field has as value the submitted data to the db, the user clicks the edit button to edit the field and THEN he clicks the cancel button, to stop editing the form...IN THE LATTER CASE I DO NOT WANT IT HIDDEN since it must display the submitted data constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on your comment, you do not want to hide an input if it has text in it. In this case allow me to refer to a snippet of the code you provided:

```
if((urlarg!=='')||(urlarg==='')){
            $('input#wwwaddress').addClass('hideurl');
            $('label[for=url]').addClass('hideurl');
}
```

The logic here reads if `urlarg` has no value or if `urlarg` has a value add a class that hides the input and label.

Thus you are hiding the input and label in all cases.

If you do not want to hide input elements when they have content, do not add the `urlarg !== ''` condition.

I also recommend adding a separate event handler for cancel and save events, such that you do not have to send special signals such as `save` to your function.

Also, as I mentioned, jquery already has a `hide`, no need to do that yourself.

Finally, you may want to trim your urlarg string, because if a user enters just a space, that's essential no value, but your script will treat it as having a value.

Comment: Let me clarify something, the above code is for data NOT SUBMITTED...that why the elements are hidden in both cases. I do not have problem with this. MY problem is clicking the cancel button when the input element opens for editing and has for value the submitted data

Comment: Then you will need additional code to handle the case when cancel is clicked to show items when they have content. Like an else statement. But I think you need to break this code up into separate event handlers and then reuse a function.

Comment: Now, I think you are getting the point. You must not forget though there are 2 cases where we have content, but the one is different than the other. In one case the content is submited data(taken from the db) and the second is when there is no submitted data and the user begins filling the field and then decides to cancel-change his/her mind.

Comment: You should define two separate handlers for each event. Try rubber duck debugging your code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging